# Convert boolean to string in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Stems from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42788713/pandas-mapping-to-true-false-as-string-not-boolean) post, but I have found a little issue with the solution.

Using `df = df.replace({True: 'TRUE', False: 'FALSE'})`, if a value is `1` or `0` it will be replaced. I only want to replace values that are actually `True` or `False` of `<class 'bool'>`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this with `df.where`, so you only replace `bool` types.

```
import pandas as pd

mask = df.applymap(type) != bool
d = {True: 'TRUE', False: 'FALSE'}

df = df.where(mask, df.replace(d))
```

#### Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'vals': [1, 0, 1.0, 'True', True, False],
                   'ids': [78, 'kitten', True, False, 'orange', 9]})
```

#### Output:

```
    vals     ids
0      1      78
1      0  kitten
2      1    TRUE
3   True   FALSE
4   TRUE  orange
5  FALSE       9
```