# Keep 'true' as string and 'True' as boolean with pandas read_csv function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Let me explain a bit better my problem.

I have a .csv that contains columns with `'False'` or `'True'` and others with `'true'` and `'false'` (note the presence of capital letters or not).

I'm ok with pandas `read_csv` function converting the first ones directly to Python boolean `True` and `False`.

However, **I want to keep `'true'` and `'false'` as strings** but they are converted to Python boolean `True` and `False`.

Is there a way to keep them as strings ?

---

I know about `true_values` optional keyword to add values to consider as True but it adds values, and not replaces values to consider True.

If come accross [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42788713/pandas-mapping-to-true-false-as-string-not-boolean) other StackOverlow post but can't apply it to my problem as I want some columns with `True` and some with `'true'` and the only way to know which columns needs to be a string or not is to read the data (but it is converted thus this post).

Thanks in advance for any help,

Comment: So you want to have a column with boolean and strings?

Comment: Have you tried to define the `dtype` of these columns to `str`?

Comment: @DanielMesejo no, each column has a separated type, when there is 'True' or 'False', I know there is only correct boolean values. However, when there is 'true' or 'false', it's only string.

Comment: @Aryerez the issue is that there is quite a lot of columns and the only way to know which columns needs to be a string or not is to read the data. And I didn't find a way to programmatically define the dtype of those specific columns.

Comment: @VictorGalisson So define them all as strings, and then read them in python.

Comment: @Aryerez getting them all as strings is not what I really want but this seems to be the most convenient solution.

Comment: if you plan on doing the type inference by yourself, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859674/converting-python-list-of-strings-to-their-type) is helpful

Answer (score 1):

illustrating Aryerez's comment, you can specify the `dtype`. given a csv 'test.csv' containing

```
a,b
True,true
False,false
```

you could call

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', dtype={'a': bool, 'b': str})
```

giving you

```
df
Out[5]: 
       a      b
0   True   true
1  False  false

df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
a    2 non-null bool
b    2 non-null object
dtypes: bool(1), object(1)
memory usage: 146.0+ bytes
```

What you could also do is mapping the column back to `str`, e.g. like in the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42788713/pandas-mapping-to-true-false-as-string-not-boolean)

```py
df['b'] = df['b'].map({True: 'true', False: 'false'})
```

However, in both cases, you require information about the data - either the name of the specific column or the columns' `dtype`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately, it means I need to find which columns need to be a string first, my issue is that to do so, I need to read the data first (which is converted).