# TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=bool)' and 'str'

Tags: python, pandas

I have this pandas DataFrame `df`:

```
         Col1    Col2
Col0
True     False   False
False    False   False
False    True    False
False    True    False
False    False   False
```

I want to substitute `False` with `No` and `True` with `Yes`:

```
bool_to_str = {'False': 'No', 'True': 'Si'}
df.replace({
        'Col1': bool_to_str,
        'Col2': bool_to_str
    }, inplace=True)


df.dtypes:

Col1   bool
Col2   bool
dtype: object
```

But get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=bool)' and 'str'
```

I checked that all columns of `df` do not contain arrays, only boolean values- For example, `df["Col1"].values[0]` returns `False`.

Comment: The dictionary should be `{False: 'No', True: 'Si'}`. so with booleans as keys.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas mapping to TRUE/FALSE as String, not Boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42788713/pandas-mapping-to-true-false-as-string-not-boolean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keys of your `bool_to_str` dictionary are *not* booleans, but strings. You should define the dictionary as:

```
bool_to_str = {False: 'No', True: 'Si'}
```

For example:

```
>>> df
    Col1   Col2
0  False  False
1  False  False
2   True  False
3   True  False
4  False  False
>>> df.replace({'Col1': {False: 'No', True: 'Si'}})
  Col1   Col2
0   No  False
1   No  False
2   Si  False
3   Si  False
4   No  False
```